# App size doubles after using Play Asset delivery in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-app-bundle

i just exported my game to use Play Asset delivery following this guide:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html

in short

- build app bundle enabled
- split application binary also checked.

The exported aab size is 311mb and when uploading to google play it says:

```
base               ----install_time  ---30.1mb
UnityDataAssetPack ----install  time ---264mb
```

[image]

But then when i download the app in any device, the file size is 846mb, more than double the expected size. Also it tries to download all at once, i thought that the dataassetpack was downloaded after the base one.

i'm using Unity 2021.1.16f1

Do you know any cause for this to happen, and how to fix it?
thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a "download size" to a "size on disk":

- The size you see in the Play Console corresponds to the **download size**, which is **compressed**.
- On the device, you see the **size on disk** where the data is stored **uncompressed** so it can be directly rendered without having to keep two copies of the same data (one compressed and one uncompressed), so that explains the discrepancy.

It seems that you have configured the modules to be **install-time** so they will be installed as part of the initial install. If you want them to be installed while the user is starting the game, you should configure them to be **fast-follow**. If you want to manually download them using the Play Core API, you should configure them to be **on-demand**. This is all explained in the [page you linked](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html) in the *Managing asset packs at runtime* section.

That page also links to the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery#delivery-modes) on the topic, which has a dedicated [section for Unity](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity) -- which would be too long to copy here, so have a read and come back if you have more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and that's my point, 800mb is the size of my app without any compression, which is weird! is seems like when uploading it it loses the compression and i can see that when using the bundle-tool, assets that wer previously compressed are no longer reduced in the resulting apks

Comment: What I was trying to explain is that Google decides that assets are better uncompressed on the device because if they were compressed, they would need to be uncompressed so they can be rendered and you'd end up with 2 copies of the assets on the device (one compressed and one uncompressed) which is bigger than just uncompressed assets. The compression in the App Bundle does not matter since it's just for uploading purposes so the smaller the better, but on the device because the asset need to be uncompressed, you should want it already uncompressed. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It makes no sense! Right now the app is uncompressed for all devices. I get that google automatically creates a new apk for each device leading to some apks being bigger than others, but right now, all of them have a download size of 800mb (where the compressed size is 300)

Comment: I think it is a bug on Unity's side, i built an aab in development mode and it all went as expected, large disk size, lower download size, i'll file a bug ticket

Comment: Where do you see that the download size is 800MB? Is that in the Play Store when the app is being downloaded? Or is it when you look at the info of the app once installed?

Comment: In the page on google play,  before download it warns you about the size and when downloading it. It is consistent, around 800 mb, no matter what device you're in.
Also there's a page to explore the package by device, all versions there are in 800mb.
it may be a chance that this is standard behaviour for an "internal test app", but it doesn't seems very likely.

Comment: I'm unsure why it would serve the uncompressed APK. Might be worth reaching out to Play Developer support and ask for someone to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using Unity marking the AAB output type in the build settings, and not using Google's API to do your stuff via script, then it's correct. Unity has a bug when assembling bundles and will simply (at least) double the size of your app. Things will be doubled in your AAB, you'll see the stuff you had in streaming assets in split apks and also inside the base.apk. Unity's way is not reliable, it's quite wrong and Google's plain way for Unity also is not perfect, it will not work for every single project. I was able to get the  hang of it, but in the end I wrote our own tool to create the asset packs, created our runtime implementation to use the API and also our build procedures to be called by our custom build class.
My suggestion is, squeeze the docs here https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity?language=api and build your custom solution.